# How to Generate an XML/XSD from a SQL Server Table?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, dotnetnuke

I'm creating a DotNetNuke module that needs to read entries from a SQL Server table called SalesOrders.  The module must only display those records where STatus = Pending.  I need to create an XML file from my database table that selects records per above.  How is this done in Visual Studio 2010?  I started to use the XML Schema Explorer to create the XSD by hand.  Not sure if this is correct approach?  Note that I'll need to do XSL transformation so that I can make the contents of the XML file available to my module, so that I can permit the user to select Invoices within a given date range.  In the module, the user needs to enable a checkbox for each invoice read from the XML file and mark them as paid.

Am I taking the proper approach relative to creating the XSD by hand, or is there a more automated approach?

Thanks much!!

Comment: Can this be done "on the fly" so that a fresh XML file is always available?

Comment: Awesome link.  Should this be done in a separate class file, or in the ascx.cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code will fill a datatable then write it to an xml string:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM  SalesOrders WHERE STatus = 'Pending'";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    dt.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    string xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    ms.Close();
    return xml;
```

you can use different methods to fill the datatable if you want

Comment: Thank you:) How do I setup joins to SalesOrderDetail and RecurringSalesOrders?  Do I create 3 separate datatables and export to 3 separate XML fiels, or 1 datatable with joins to the other 2 tables from SalesOrders?  If 3 separate datatables, do I call WriteXml for each one separately?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DataTable` from the SQL Server Table and then use then use [DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml.aspx) to export data to `XML` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way.

```
DECLARE @xmlDoc XML
SET @xmlDoc =
  (
      SELECT * from Employees where EmployeeID IN     (7032,7478,6967,6862,6861,7469,6947,6951,7009,7010)
      FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, BINARY BASE64
  )
SELECT @xmlDoc
```